# Batch convert .pcm files to .wav files in PowerShell using ffmpeg

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, converters, batch-processing

I'm trying to make a script that converts all .pcm files in a folder to .wav files using ffmpeg.
Following files are in the same folder:

- the script (.ps1)
- ffmpeg.exe
- the .pcm audio files

```
$oldfiles = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.pcm" -Recurse
foreach ($oldfile in $oldfiles) {
    $newfile = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($oldfile, '.wav')
    .\ffmpeg.exe -f s16le -ar 24000 -i $oldfile $newfile
}
```

For some reason the script is doing nothing and the .pcm files just persist in the folder.

Run the script with PowerShell within the same folder of the .pcm files and ffmpeg.exe.
I would expect that the .pcm were converted to .wav files.

Comment: Do you mean you are surprised the .pcm files are not removed after converting them to .wav?

Comment: No, the actual conversion just doesn't seem to happen.

Comment: `[io.path]::ChangeExtension($oldfile.FullName, '.wav')`. You are feeding a FileInfo **object** to the .net method where it needs a **string** (the full path and filename of the pcm file). Also I'd recommend adding switch `-File` to the Get-ChildItem cmd to make sure it doesn't pick up folders as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script and it worked, I assume the error is in the files you're working with, so you can paste the whole script in a powershell (multiline) and you can read what error you have.

#### but anyhow I had to write another while debugging some things so here's the script:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Path\to\Source\Folder"
$destinationFolder = "C:\Path\to\Destination\Folder"

# Get all PCM audio files in the source folder
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter "*.pcm" -File

# Loop through each PCM audio file
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $inputFile = $file.FullName
    $outputFile = Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath ($file.BaseName + ".wav")

    # Execute FFmpeg command to convert MS ADPCM to WAV
    & ffmpeg -ac 2 -i $inputFile -c:a adpcm_ms $outputFile
}
```

**Make sure to edit this line:**

```
ffmpeg -ac 2 -i $inputFile -c:a adpcm_ms $outputFile
```

**according to the following:**

- **-ac** is the number of channels, you can remove it to have ffmpeg guess that number.
- **-c:a** is the codec that the file in encoded in. *some options are: aac, mp3, opus, vorbis, flac, alac, pcm_s16le, wavpack.*

##### You can use this line instead to just copy the audio data from one file to the other:

```
ffmpeg -i $inputFile -c:a copy $outputFile
```

This script assumes you have ffmpeg in your path environment, if not here's how to add it:

1. Download ffmpeg executable: *https://ffmpeg.org/download.html*.
2. Extract it somewhere safe where it won't be moved. *(C:\ffmpeg)*.
3. Copy the path where ffmpeg.exe is. *(C:\ffmpeg\bin)*.
4. Type system variables into the search bar and click Edit system environment variables.
5. Under User variables section, select Path and click Edit.
6. Click new and paste the path from step 3.
7. restart any terminal you have opened.

If you have any problems, remember to paste the script directly in powershell to read any error messages.